# Strict standards: Declaration of Zend_Gdata::import() should be

Tags: wamp, blogger

I downloaded Zend_Gdata on Zend.com. I installed Zend_Gdata on Wamp server on windows follow this tut:
https://developers.google.com/gdata/articles/php_client_lib?hl=ja

I download this file to check my installation: 
http://framework.zend.com/svn/framework/standard/trunk/demos/Zend/Gdata/InstallationChecker.php
I also try enable openssl extentions in wamp server.
But i received an error message:

> Strict standards: Declaration of Zend_Gdata::import() should be
>   compatible with Zend_Gdata_App::import($uri, $client = NULL,
>   $className = 'Zend_Gdata...', $useObjectMapping = true) in
>   C:\Zend\library\Zend\Gdata.php on line 45

What is my problem?

Comment: i don't, but i remove it and install again, it worked

Answer (score 0):

You can change import function in Zend/Gdata.php to fix this issue.

Find below line (appx on line 123).

```
public static function import($uri, $client = null,
    $className='Zend_Gdata_Feed')
```

Replace with below one.

```
public static function import($uri, $client = null,
    $className='Zend_Gdata_Feed', $useObjectMapping = true)
```